# Is it required or advised to sterilize bottles?

Tags: newborn, bottle-feeding

So we've been sterilizing our bottles with a microwave steam bottle sterilizer. Is this at all required? What risks might exist if we don't bother?

Comment: Related question:[Is it necessary to boil the water for baby formula in Switzerland?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/24168/is-it-necessary-to-boil-the-water-for-baby-formula-in-switzerland).

Answer (score 15):

The current scientific consensus is:

**No.
It is not necessary to sterilize bottles, not even for newborns.**

The only exception are bottle teats made of rubber - the rubber can become porous over time, so occasional sterilization is recommended. However, most bottle teats are made of silicone, which is not affected.

The primary safety measure to take with milk bottles is to *not let them sit for too long*, because harmful germs do develop if the milk is not fresh. However, if the milk is fresh, sterilizing the bottle does not make a difference.

*Caveat:*

This assumes the bottles are thoroughly cleaned just like regular dishes, and that they are cleaned with safe drinking water, such as tap water in most developed nations. If there is no access to safe drinking water for cleaning this answer does not apply.

---

Source:

*"Säuglingsernährung und Ernährung der stillenden Mutter - Handlungsempfehlungen"* ("Nutrition of babies and of breastfeeding mothers - practical guidelines"), published in Monatsschrift
Kinderheilkunde, October 2010. [Original publication (paywalled)](https://www.springermedizin.de/saeuglingsernaehrung-und-ernaehrung-der-stillenden-mutter/8048772), [alternative source (free to read)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225718378_Sauglingsernahrung_und_Ernahrung_der_stillenden_Mutter).

This is a comprehensive document on nutrition, jointly authored by multiple physicians and nutrition experts from hospitals, research institutes and German government institutes.

It has a paragraph on hygiene:

> Hygienische Aspekte.
>
> Das  hygienische Hauptrisiko liegt in der Vermehrung
>   gesundheitsgefährdender  Bakterien,  wie Escherichia coli und
>   Salmonellen. Es wird entscheidend  von  den  Standzeiten  der
>   zubereiteten  Milchnahrung  beeinflusst. Deshalb sollen
>   Milchnahrungsreste entsorgt und nicht wieder aufgewärmt werden.  Dies 
>   ist  die  entscheidende  hygienische Vorsichtsmaßnahme. Ein Auskochen
>   bzw. Sterilisieren der Flaschen und  Sauger bringen keinen weiteren
>   Vorteil. Dies stellen alle Fachorganisationen fest (DGE, DGKJ, FKE).
>
> Gummisauger werden im Gegensatz zu Silikonsaugern porös. Deshalb
>   sollten sie Deshalb sollten sie aus Sicht der Experten/-innen hin und
>   wieder ausgekocht  werden.

English translation (by me, no guarantees):

> Hygiene aspects
>
> The main hygiene risk is the growth of harmful bacteria, like
>   escherichia coli and salmonellae. This is largely determined by the time
>   the milk is left to stand. Therefore milk leftovers should be disposed of,
>   and not reheated. This is the most important hygiene precaution. Boiling
>   or sterilizing the bottles and teats does not provide an additional
>   advantage. This is the consensus among all professional organizations
>   (DGE, DGKJ, FKE).
>
> Rubber teats, unlike silicone teats, can become porous. Therefore the
>   experts recommend to boil them from time to time.

Comment: Hi sleske - welcome to the site.  Thanks for such a thorough answer!

Comment: While I completely accept the evidence you've provided, as an interesting aside, I had heard before that the standard advice in Germany is that there's no need to sterilise.  Here in the UK the advice is that all equipment *must* be sterilised. http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/pages/making-up-infant-formula.aspx Go figure! I would point out that the Germans seem to be surviving their lax attitudes very well! ☺

Comment: @ctokelly: Yes, interesting difference. According to Wikipedia's [Baby bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_bottle#Cleaning_and_sterilization) article, the NHS recommends sterilization, while WebMD.com says it is not necessary.

Comment: @ctokelly - put that in an answer!

Answer (score 8):

**No, it's not required.** Lots of children are born into dirty surroundings and still survive.

**Yes, it's advised** for newborns and infants because they have not yet built up enough immune resistance. Baby bottles, teething toys, and other objects that the newborn/infant puts in the mouth can be sterilized to reduce any unnecessary burden on the child.

Once the kids start sucking on all kinds of non-sterilized toys, non-toys, *stroller wheels!*, etc. you can stop sterilizing.

While you *are* still sterilizing, be sure to read and follow the instructions carefully. It's very easy to contaminate a newly-sterilized set of bottles with a thoughtless hand movement.

PS: When we were expecting, we were lured into the fear trap and bought a brand-new Philips sterilizer. We could probably have found the same used for much less, or even a kit that can be used in the microwave like you mention. Fear can help people open their eyes and do a little basic research (good), or it can sucker them into spending more than they have to (silly).

Comment: Any evidence to support your opinion?

Comment: Well @Dan you already saw the link that ctokelly provided. My answer (four years ago...) is based on personal experience and the advice we have received from infant health care workers.

Answer (score 4):

Babies take a while to build up resistance to infection, so sterilising bottles, at least for the first few months, is definitely recommended. Milk is a very good food not only for babies, but for bacteria so you want to get bottles clean, and then sterilised!

Answer (score 2):

On a daily basis, sterilization is not necessary, particularly if these things are washed with soap and hot water shortly after use.

However, when someone in the home gets sick, the bottles, nipples, pacifiers and mouthy-toys should be sterilized. Also any items left unwashed for a while (like the pacifier tied to the stroller) could use sterilization from time to time.

It was easy for me to sterilize because we had an electric dishwasher, which gets hot enough for long enough to kill bacteria. We put the nipples and small items in a special basket, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I use bottle to feed my baby. My doctor advised me to sterilize the bottles on daily basis.Because it is not possible to create a totally germ-free environment so sterilizing baby bottles is very important otherwise bacteria, viruses and parasites can gather and make baby ill. Continue it for one year so that the baby will start producing their own antibodies and be resistant to harmful germs and bacteria. If it is possible continue it until your baby stops using them.

I use electric steam sterilizer for sterilizing.

Comment: Yes I agree. If your pediatrician advised you to sterilize daily, do it. Water differs in cleanliness place to place. Living in a 3rd world country like me this is necessary as we are not assured of the cleanliness of our water. Nipples are resistant to high heat, considering it is sterilized in 10mins in an electric sterilizer it will be used in a the long run.