# Bottle sterilizers and their effectiveness

Tags: safety, bottle-feeding, pacifier, temperatures

I have a baby on the way and I am looking into bottle sterilizers.  My concern is if they are really effective at disinfecting.  Some claim to disinfect in as little as 5 minutes.  I am not sure that is enough exposure time.  I am also having a hard time finding actual specification as to what temperatures the sterilizer reaches.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jake. Two similar Questions that you might also find useful: [Is it required or advised to sterilize bottles?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/is-it-required-or-advised-to-sterilize-bottles) and [What are the sterilization techniques available to sterilize bottles and nipples?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/what-are-the-sterilization-techniques-available-to-sterilize-bottles-and-nipples). I think you're more specifically interested in "technical" information about sterilizing (what temp it needs to be at and for how long), though.

Comment: You included the "pacifier" tag -- does this mean you are interested in sterilizing pacifiers in addition to bottles? (The same methods would typically apply, I believe.)

Comment: Unless your child is immunosuppressed, for your first child you'll sterilize the heck out of everything. 90 degrees C is about right (not 90 F). By your second child you'll sterilize only when you don't plan to use it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Sterilization using solely water or steam would indeed take more than five minutes.  Steam that is just at 100°C would take close to [an hour and a half](http://generalbacteriology.weebly.com/sterilization-and-disinfection.html) to completely sterilize the vessels - and a better process is to repeat it several times (Tyndallization, referenced in that article as well).

However, you're not just using steam here; you're also washing the bottles in soapy water.  You also don't have to get to the level of cleanliness that a clean room requires - here there is a misuse of the word "Sterilized".  You want "sanitized".  A couple of bacteria here or there won't be a disaster - you just need there to be not enough to cause the milk to go bad or make your baby sick.  (You're probably not being sufficiently careful with the bottles post-sterilization, anyway.)  Sanitizing means reducing the level of bacteria by [99.999%](http://www.foodprocessing.com/articles/2010/007/).

Boiling or steaming for 5-10 minutes is usually the recommended time.  Restaurants sanitize their dishes in 85°C water for 15 minutes; as water gets hotter, it's more effective at sanitizing.  Note that this is as a third step after washing and rinsing - just like restaurants - and does not remove any particulate objects.

If your baby has a medical condition that requires more care than that, please ask your doctor for the specifics.  You *can* sterilize at home, either using chemical sterilization agents or steam, but it's much more involved than the bottle steamers that you're buying at Buy Buy Baby or whatnot.